# How to draw hierarchical graph like this one?

Tags: forest

I want to draw the graph like this [image].
However, I only came this one,
[image]

it seems so ugly. I am frustrated, can anyone help me to get what I wanted?

My code is given as follows

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30} 
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20} 
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
 rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                     inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
 ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                      outer color = col5out},
 orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries,
                      text width = 280pt, text centered,
                     minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col3out},  
 oellip/.append style = {ellip, 
                      font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}
\begin{forest}
 for tree={
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  line width=1pt,
  draw=linecol,
  ellip,
  align=center,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  drop shadow,
  l sep+=12.5pt,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
      >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  where level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
  where level={0}{l sep-=15pt}{},
  where level={1}{
    if n={1}{
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
          >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
          \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.west) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
    }{
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
          >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
          \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.east) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        }, 
     }
    }{}, 
  }
   [Dynamic Object, outer color=col3out
    [Senor 1
    [Filter, rect, name=sse1
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 2
    [Filter, rect, name=sse2
    ]
  ]
  [, phantom, calign with current
    [A\\B, phantom
      [Mutli-Sensor Fusion, orect, name=us
        [{Consensus}, oellip
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 3
    [Filter, rect, name=sse3
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 4
    [Filter, rect, name=sse4
    ]
  ]
]
  \begin{scope}[color = linecol, rounded corners = 5pt,
    >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->]
    \draw (sse2.south) -- (us.north -| sse2.south);
    \draw (sse3.south) -- (us.north -| sse3.south);
    \coordinate (c1) at ($(sse1.south)!2/5!(sse2.south)$);
    \coordinate (c2) at ($(sse3.south)!2/5!(sse4.south)$);
    \draw (sse1.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (us.north -| c1);
    \draw (sse4.south) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (us.north -| c2);
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it looks better than the original, but watch the spelling.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Thanks, the following Harish's answer looks much more better than original. Watch my spelling? I do not understand, can you specify?

Comment: "sensor" rather than "senor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, calc, shadows,fit}

\colorlet{mygreen}{green!75!black}
\colorlet{col1in}{red!30}
\colorlet{col1out}{red!40}
\colorlet{col2in}{mygreen!40}
\colorlet{col2out}{mygreen!50}
\colorlet{col3in}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col3out}{blue!40}
\colorlet{col4in}{mygreen!20}
\colorlet{col4out}{mygreen!30}
\colorlet{col5in}{blue!10}
\colorlet{col5out}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6in}{blue!20}
\colorlet{col6out}{blue!30}
\colorlet{col7out}{orange}
\colorlet{col7in}{orange!50}
\colorlet{col8out}{orange!40}
\colorlet{col8in}{orange!20}
\colorlet{linecol}{blue!60}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/forest,
 rect/.append style   = {rectangle, rounded corners = 2pt,
                     inner color = col6in, outer color = col6out},
 ellip/.append style  = {ellipse, inner color = col5in,
                      outer color = col5out},
 orect/.append style  = {rect, font = \sffamily\bfseries,
                      text width = 280pt, text centered,
                     minimum height = 10pt, outer color = col3out},
 oellip/.append style = {ellip,
                      font = \sffamily\bfseries\large, text centered}}
\begin{forest}
 for tree={
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  line width=1pt,
  draw=linecol,
  ellip,
  align=center,
  child anchor=north,
  parent anchor=south,
  drop shadow,
  l sep=1cm,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
      >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -|
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  where level={3}{tier=tier3}{},
  where level={0}{l sep-=15pt}{},
  where level={1}{
    if n={1}{
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
          >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
          \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south) --++(0,-8pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
    }{
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=linecol, rounded corners=5pt,
          >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->,
          \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.south) --++(0,-8pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
     }
    }{},
  }
   [Dynamic Object,l sep=1.5cm, outer color=col3out
    [Senor 1,name=senor1,
    [Filter, rect, name=sse1
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 2,name=senor2,
    [Filter, rect, name=sse2
    ]
  ]
  [, phantom, calign with current
    [A\\B, phantom
      [Mutli-Sensor Fusion, orect, name=us
        [{Consensus}, oellip
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 3,name=senor3,
    [Filter, rect, name=sse3
    ]
  ]
  [Senor 4,name=senor4,
    [Filter, rect, name=sse4
    ]
  ]
]
  \begin{scope}[color = linecol, rounded corners = 5pt,
    >={Stealth[length=10pt]}, line width=1pt, ->]
    \draw (sse2.south) -- (us.north -| sse2.south);
    \draw (sse3.south) -- (us.north -| sse3.south);
    \coordinate (c1) at ($(sse1.south)!2/5!(sse2.south)$);
    \coordinate (c2) at ($(sse3.south)!3/5!(sse4.south)$);
    \draw (sse1.south) -- +(0,-22pt) -| (us.north -| c1);
    \draw (sse4.south) -- +(0,-22pt) -| (us.north -| c2);
    \node[draw,dash dot,fit=(senor1)(sse4)(senor4),inner ysep=12pt,]{};
    \coordinate (m1) at ($(sse2)!0.5!(senor2)$);
    \coordinate (m2) at ($(senor2)!0.5!(senor3)$);
    \node[scale=3] at (m1-|m2) {.....};
  \end{scope}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, thank you very much, it's nice. I have another question: I wanna draw "..." between "sensor 2" and "sensor 3" just like the original graph, how to work it out?

Comment: @WangyanLi If you give names to the 2 phantom nodes, `p` and `q`, say, then you can put `\node at ($(p)!1/2!(q)$) {\dots};` in the group of drawing commands following the specification of the tree.

Comment: (+1) I would adjust the dotted rectangle so that the tips of the arrows are within its boundaries and move the curves from the outermost 'Filter' nodes a bit downwards so that the `ysep` above and below the tree to the dotted lines remains roughly equal.

Comment: @cfr Your wish is my command :-) Done.

Comment: @HarishKumar Many thanks to you, I have learnt a lot from you!

Comment: I can't upvote again ;). (And I already upvoted your other `forest` today too, so I can't even compensate there!)

Comment: @cfr Your suggestion is well appreciated.

Comment: @WangyanLi This isn't based on an answer of mine, by any chance, is it? I think `orect` originally stood for 'orange rectangle', for example...

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's based on your work, I found this from [Example: Hierarchical diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hierarchical-diagram/) and modified it to the creepy graph posted in my question. I'm so embarrassed.

Comment: @WangyanLi You are welcome. Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: @WangyanLi Why? Glad you found it helpful:).